# Is there a way to modify Linux syscall table in a proprietary kernel module?

Tags: c, security, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I wrote an kind of SELinux clone that supervises system call execution such as open and execve.

The result is proven by SELinux as a secure way to monitor all disk access made by users.

The code modifies the syscall table in the following way:

> 1. Change the name->address relationship of a syscall
> 2. After the change, the syscall name is my own function, which then calls the original syscall.
> 3. the original syscall address is protected by address space layout randomization which requires scanning 16 exabytes of data, and the
>      address changes with every reboot.

Old trick, but the only way I found to achieve this is via a service routine exported only to GPL modules with the following code:

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Is there a way to discover either the syscall table or the syscall address without a GPL kernel module?

Answer (score 1):

You did it wrong. Syscall wrapping is the standard TOCTOU bug class factory. See this paper http://www.watson.org/~robert/2007woot/2007usenixwoot-exploitingconcurrency.pdf

In fact, LSM hooks (used to implement selinux) are precisely what you need to actually get this to work in a secure manner. But then there is no use of overwriting anything in the syscall table.

Comment: Sorry for removing the acceptance, as LSM is requires a patch, and not LKM. Also, I'll study the paper then accept if applicable, but it seems that the vulnerabilities you mentioned only apply to users who already have root access.

Comment: Problems described in the paper stem from the fact that wrappers around open and similar syscalls duplicate part of the work of the wrapped syscall in a racy manner - the target file can be validated as fine for use and in the time window between finished validation and the call to wrapped open  replaced with a file which would not pass the test. Effectively bypassing the check. This is most definitely not root-specific.

Comment: Verify when? The entire point is that after the *wrapper* finishes the validation and let's the real open do the work, the target file can be something completely different. With LSM you get a call with the file already found by open. Then if you let it through, this is the file you which will be returned.

Comment: This applies to monitoring 'open' only, but if disk access is monitored, how could one replace the file for 'open'? the arguments have already been passed.

Comment: Also, i don't currently have a post stage, but theoretically I can lock the file in pre stage and release the lock in post.

Comment: Have you read the paper? your wrapper performs the lookup. then someone replaces the file (e.g. if the passed path is /foo/bar/baz/, they mv /foo/bar /foo/crap; mv /foo/new /foo/bar. now /foo/bar/baz is not the same file.). why do you insist on using a wrapper?

Comment: I haven't finished studying the paper. Tomorrow I'll try to implement a post stage to see if I can lock rename(2). LSM requires patching and recompiling the kernel as opposed to LKM which can be loaded via dpkg/apt, that's why. added +1 for the info but cannot accept as answer right now.

Comment: I don't recommend it, but... you are already willing to effectively hack the kernel (overwrite system call table entries) to make it do what you want. I don't see a fundamental difference between this and overwriting pointers to lsm hooks. Both approaches are rather fishy, but the latter happens to not suffer from the races mentioned in the paper.